# Javascript namespacing throwing error in IE

Tags: javascript

In my project I create modules for each webpage and add to a base object called `View`:

**App.js**

```
var View = (function()  {

    var View  = function()  {
        this.attributes = {
            baseUrl : '',
            urls : {}
        };
    };

    View.prototype.setUrl = function(url)   {
        this.attributes.baseUrl = url;
    };

    View.prototype.getUrl = function()  {
        return this.attributes.baseUrl;
    };

    return new View();

})();
```

**SearchView.js**

```
var View = View || {};

var SearchView = View.SearchView = (function()  {

    var Private = {
        search : function(url)  {},
        loadSearchResult : function()   {},
        clearSearchForm : function()    {}
    };

    Private.search = function(url)  {
        ajax(url,...);
        this.loadSearchResult();
    };

    var SearchView = function() {
        this.settings = {};
    };

    SearchView.prototype.loadEventBindind = function()  {
        $(document)

        .on('click','#search-button', function()    {
            Private.search(View.baseUrl);
        })

        .on('click','#reset-search', function() {
            Private.clearSearchForm();
        });
    };

    return new SearchView();

})();
```

**search.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/scripts/Modules/App.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/scripts/View/SearchView.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    View.setUrl('http://www.set.com/');
    View.SearchView.loadEventBindings();
</script>
```

This code works properly in Chrome and Firefox, but throws an error in IE:

> '`View.SearchView`' is `null` or not an object

Does IE not support this way of creating objects?

Comment: @Martin i am not using backbone.js

Comment: Sorry, I've confused with other post. 
About the error, I've had many errors using double assignation in IE. Did you try changing this: var SearchView = View.SearchView = (function()  ... for this View.SearchView = (function()  { ....; var SearchView = View.SearchView; ??

Comment: no prob martin.. i use this convention for modules related to a webpage.. like for search.html - SearchView, home.html - HomeView etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you should do:

You have a weak point in that your App.js script could overwrite `View` object created by SearchView.js.

- Don't use one variable as both namespace and class. It's counter intuitive.
- If you're already writing singletons, there is no need to use prototype pattern, although there's nothing wrong with it. You won't save any memory though.

---

If you're sticking your guns to using View as class and namespace, make changes like this to prevent `View` being overwritten.

```
var View = View || {};
var ViewTmp;
$.extend(ViewTmp = (function()  {

    var View  = function()  {
    ...
  ...
})(), View);
View = ViewTmp;
```

This script assumes that you are using jQuery (because of `$.extend` method).

Comment: if i removes the var View = View || {}; line in the SearchView.js does it work.

Comment: Why do you need to remove that line? It MAY work, but then again you are in same problem as before. One script may overwrite `View` set by the other script.

Comment: sorry for the very late reply. let me check the code you suggested.